# Elasticsearch _source include a specific array item from the document

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-net

My document looks like this

```
{
            "_index": "mydb",
            "_type": "target",
            "_id": "AV8vO5O0eCTee14x6VZQ",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "line": "77.001",
               "parameters": [
                  {
                     "parameterType": "Lift",
                     "coefficients": [
                        {
                           "name": "Margin"
                        },
                        {
                           "name": "Sales"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "parameterType": "Display",
                     "coefficients": [
                        {
                           "name": "Front"
                        },
                        {
                           "name": "Back"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
```

In my search response i need to include one particular `coefficients` for a particular `parameterType`.
For example i want `Margin` for `Lift`  & `Back` for `Display`

**Question is how to i write my request?** Eventually i need to write it in NEST code.

request:

```
post mydb/target/_search
{
    "_source":{
        "include": [/*What should i write here?*/]
    }
}
```

response:

```
{
            "_index": "mydb",
            "_type": "target",
            "_id": "AV8vO5O0eCTee14x6VZQ",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "line": "77.001",
               "parameters": [
                  {
                     "parameterType": "Lift",
                     "coefficients": [
                        {
                           "name": "Margin"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "parameterType": "Display",
                     "coefficients": [
                        {
                           "name": "Back"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
```

Comment: This cannot be done with source filtering. You need to map those parameters as nested type and include a nested filter in order to get back only the nested elements that you need. Source filtering is only useful for filtering by name and not by value.

Comment: @Val could you please add an answer and show how the initial document and the request should look like?